# Analysis of consecutive abences using DAX language

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have a fact table recording student presence and absence.
In this table, there are columns such as:

- class code
- school code
- academic calendar code
- student code
- class period code
- date of the class
- description of the student's status, with "Present" being the status of the student who was in class and "Absent" for the student who was not in class.

I need to count the number of consecutive absences for each student, making a temporal analysis for each student.

In other words, from the date of the class, scroll through the days prior to that date, disregarding holidays, and counting absences in two or more consecutive days. Accounting must stop when, after consecutive days of absence, there is a presence, and must be restarted when new absences occur on two or more consecutive days.
How to make this all possible, using the DAX language?

I have already applied different codes and none of them returned the desired result.

Comment: Can you share some data and expected output ?